# How to give each textfield and label a name in this code? JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, swing

below I have pasted my java code which I need a bit help with. How would I refer to each individual textbox and label? e.g. I have created a code that loops through the array list and create appropriate amount of labels and textfields in my case below it creates 3 of each. The problem I am having is, how would I refer to each of these components? for example, if i want to get the value of my second textbox how would I do that? is there any way to give each textbox and textfield a name. e.g. say first label name is label1, second is label2 and so on and first textbox name is field1, second box name is field2 and so on.

Comment: Just declare them as class members, ff you only have three of each. It's much easier to maintain that way.

Comment: in this example i have only used 3 but I have like 8-10 in total.

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: I have to no clue how to refer to each textfield or label. say for example I want to get the value of the first field, how would I do that or I want to disable my second label, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve them from the Map with their associated key.

```
String textOfFirst = fieldMap.get("Text1").getText();
fieldMap.get("Text2").setEnabled(false);
```

But as my opinion, it seems like with this kind of group creation you should have it set up so you don't need to refer to them individually.

Comment: How would I refer to each field?

Comment: Is there any way to give each component a unique name, e.g. label1, 2 and 3, field1, 2 and 3. Basically, I need to get the value of each field and pass it onto a new variable which I need to use for something else.

Comment: By putting them in a Map with an associated key, that's effectively what you've done. Their 'names' are `"Text1", "Text2", ...`. You must pull them from the Map if you want to use them individually. Otherwise I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: for example I have  variable called A, and a textfield called B. To get and pass the value of textfield to variable A, I would do something like A = B.getText();

Comment: Well since you've put your text fields in a Map, you don't have a text field called B. You have text fields you can retrieve from the Map with their associated key. Given the keys you used in the OP, the code I show in my answer is how to retrieve your text fields from your Map. If you want to give your text fields identifiers, you can't use a Map.

Comment: that was just an example. I want to know how I can do that with this code.

Comment: My answer shows you how to do that. You have to retrieve them from the Map. @peeskillet has posted a longer example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example you can run. I used a `Map` as you were trying to do. There may be a lot of code, but what your interested in is this

```
Map<String, JTextField> fields;
....
JTextField field = new JTextField(15);
fields.put(fieldName, field);
....
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        String fieldName = button.getText();
        JTextField field = fields.get(fieldName);
        System.out.println(field.getText());
    }
}
```

I just put the `JTextField` in a `Map`. When I want to access it, I just use `JTextField field = fields.get("textfield name");`

In the example below, just type in something to the field, then click the button next to it. You will see that the button has the same name as the text field key in the map, so I just use that to print the value in the text field

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test2 {

    Map<String, JTextField> fields;
    Map<String, JLabel> labels;

    public Test2() {
        fields = new HashMap<>();
        labels = new HashMap<>();

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 1));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            JPanel panel = createPanel("Text Field " + i);
            mainPanel.add(panel);
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new Test2();
            }
        });
    }

    private JPanel createPanel(String fieldName) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField field = new JTextField(15);
        field.addActionListener(new FieldListener());
        fields.put(fieldName, field);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(fieldName);
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
        labels.put(fieldName, label);

        JButton button = new JButton(fieldName);
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(field);
        panel.add(button);

        return panel;
    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
            String fieldName = button.getText();
            JTextField field = fields.get(fieldName);
            System.out.println(field.getText());
        }
    }

    public class FieldListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JTextField field = (JTextField)e.getSource();
            System.out.println(field.getText());
        }
    }

    public class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
            System.out.println(label.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, I get it now but I am little confused. So both the textfield and textbox share the same variable? so for example, like rediodef said, to get the value in the textfield, I need to String textOfFirst = fieldMap.get("Text1").getText(); and to get the text of the label I just replace the fieldmap with JTextField?

Comment: No, I used the text of the button as an example. Where the button has the same text as the text field's map key.

Comment: It tough without a little more context into what exactly you're trying to achieve, to give you a definitive answer. Maybe give an explanation as to what event would what to happen. Then maybe I could offer some more insight. This is just an example. But it may not fit what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: K 1 sec. I am going to edited my post and try to explain is better